# Initialize class instance with initializer_list if class has base with virtual methods c++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, initializer-list

How to initialize class instance with initializer_list if class has base with virtual methods c++? I want to avoid writing constructors and use "lazy" way to initialize class like `X x{"Some string"};`. But I got

> error: no matching function for call to ‘X::X(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

Is any way to simply initialize X instance without significant changing of classes?

```
struct Y
{
    virtual ~Y() = 0;
};
struct X : public Y
{
    string msg;
    virtual ~X() = default;
};
int main()
{
    X x{"Some string"};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want aggregate initialization for a class that's not an aggregate. You can't have it, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: The main problem is that because you have polymorphic classes (classes with virtual functions), the classes can't be *aggregates* which would have allowed the shown [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). You must create a constructor to make it work with non-aggregate classes.

Comment: There's no `initializer_list` here, just a list in braces.

Comment: What you see here is an example of what's typically called [Uniform Initialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init). A mostly successful attempt at unifying and simplifying C++ initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already answer it. Here is a summary.

**Short answer**

No, there is no way - because that would be a aggregate initialisation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) that is only possible when the class (struct) has:

- no user-declared constructors
- no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors
- no user-declared or inherited constructors
- no private or protected direct (since C++17) non-static data members
- **no base classes**
- no virtual base classes
- **no virtual member functions**
- no default member initializers

**Alternative 1**

If there is just the attribute `string msg`, then you can do the following.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

struct Y
{
    virtual ~Y() = default; // !!! not pure virtual !!!
};

struct X : public Y
{
    string msg;
    virtual ~X() = default;
};

int main( int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[] )
{
    X   x;
    x.msg = "Some string";
    cout << "int main( int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[] ) - #1" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: In the code above, the destructor has been changed to `virtual ~Y() = default;` otherwise the compiler complains about the missing destructor that is called from `~X()`. Linker error, may be:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "m1::Y::~Y()", referenced from:
      m1::X::~X() in m1.o
```

NOTE: You may have no constructor that assures the consistency of states after construction.

**Alternative 2**

Make your attribute list a tuple.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

struct Y
{
    virtual ~Y() = default;
};

typedef string TMessage;
typedef int TOtherAttribute;

using XAttributes = std::tuple<TMessage, TOtherAttribute>;

struct X : public Y
{
    XAttributes mx;
    X( XAttributes l ) : mx{ l } {
    };
    virtual ~X() = default;
    template<typename T> void print() const {
        cout << "member = " << get<T>( mx ) << '\n';
    }
};

int main( int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[] )
{
    X   x{ XAttributes{ "Some string", 34 } };
    x.print<TMessage>();
    x.print<TOtherAttribute>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
member = Some string
member = 34
```